# Eine Feier, auf die ich mich gefreut habe, wurde abgesagt. Grammatik und Zeichensetzung

Tags: punctuation

> Eine Geburtstagsfeier, auf die ich mich gefreut habe, wurde abgesagt.

Ist die Zeichensetzung korrekt? Wie nennt man den Satzteil *auf die ich mich gefreut habe*?

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Worin besteht der Zweifel, ob die Zeichensetzung korrekt ist? Was sind die bekannten/ gefühlten Regeln, die hier nach eigenem Wissensstand relevant sind?

Comment: Weil die Freude zeitlich vor der vergangenen Absage liegt, ist das Plusquamperfekt richtig: ...auf die ich mich gefreut hatte, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das ist ein gewöhnlicher [Relativsatz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativsatz). Die allgemeine Regel ist, dass Relativsätze an beiden Seiten mit Komma abgeteilt werden, sie ist hier also erfüllt.

Answer (score 1):

Relativsätze lassen sich außerdem leicht daran erkennen, dass sie eher zusätzliche Informationen enthalten und der Rest des Satzkonstruktes kaum Schaden nimmt, wenn man den Relativsatz wegließe.